# Windows phone 7 App Idle Detection

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am working on a application in which there are some 10 phone application pages. Whenever the user enter the app the application asks to enter password and then application continues. What I need is whenever the user doesn't interact with the app for some one minute I want the app to go unlock screen and once again ask the user to enter the password.

How can I know that user is not interacting with the application in windows phone 7?

Comment: It's really really terrible UX to ask the user for credentials constantly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would expect an application that behaves in such a way to be loathed by the users of it. But if you *must* then you simply need to reset a timer every time something that you consider as "activity" within your app happens. Presumably this'll be some form of user interaction such as page navigation or interacting/tapping/editing content.

It's crude but it'll work. It'll also negatively impact the battery too. You have been warned.

Comment: How can we get input from all the pages?

Comment: It'll depend on your app. You'll need to add something in the handlers (or commands) of every action though.